# What's that layer under the cork underlayment?

Tags: flooring

I had a small water damage in the kitchen and the drying company removed part of the kitchen flooring. Now I want to redo the kitchen floor by myself. The current structure can be seen from the picture below: concrete -> an thin unidentified layer -> cork -> some soft top floor material. The cork seems to be attached to the thin layer below.

My questions:

1. What's that thin layer made of? What are the possibilities?
2. How to best remove the cork layer from the thin layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cork underlayment is usually glued to the flooring underneath.

There is some glue with cork still stuck to it, in the pic.

Getting the cork removed is a tedious process of scraping and sweeping and vacuuming.

What's under the cork, looks like vinyl sheet flooring. Scraping the cork off will pull off the top layer of the vinyl in some spots, leaving a ragged mixture of vinyl, a paper like inner layer and the bare concrete.

The good news is the old vinyl is so thin that laying new 1/4 inch cork over the ragged floor will be ok, if you don't want to scrape everything off.

Comment: The texture of the layer under the cork and glue feels like cement too, but finer than the real cement subfloor. It appears to be a material that was spread over the subfloor, rather than a sheet.

Comment: @Aufheben, That probably is a leveling compound. It is cement based.  best to not try to scrape that off.

Comment: @RMDmand Thanks! After some research I also concluded that it's most likely leveling compound.